# How to call REST-API of Zoom from Angular 11 directly?

Tags: angular, cross-domain, angular11, zoom-sdk

Everybody. i am come with a problem that answer i could not found google. so i asked.

problem is when i try to calling **Zoom** any **API** then i am greeting error **CROS** that is below. i used **proxy server** for this but not working .so i removed this from **anguler.json**.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/La------77/meetings' 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource.
```

i am setting **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'** but not working. i configure proxy server but it was being redirect on Zoom site.

> check my code

```
fetchAllMeetings(){
    let header = new HttpHeaders({  "Authorization": "Bearer "+this.CLIENT_TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'   });

         const requestOptions = {  headers: header};

    return this.httpClient.get('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/LayQ----FTgmw/meetings',requestOptions).pipe(first(), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

> Response Error

[image]

> API Call

[image]

I setup proxy server for this...  but removed because i was redirect in zoom website.

> src/proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "*": {
    "target": "https://api.zoom.us",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Zoom-Meeting:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"

          },
```

Comment: Check the proxy config path in angular.json. It must be - "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json" and not "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json".

Comment: hope it worked !!? @pankaj kumar

Comment: yes  i have file in  src/proxy.config.json

Comment: no bro its not working,  right now i have disabled it. so i am not using proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've misunderstood the CORS error response you got.
CORS settings are made by the zoom api. Zoom does not allow an unknown domain (in your case localhost:4200) to access that uesrs/----/meetings endpoint. I'm afraid there is nothing you can do to make this work.

Comment: ok, thanks. i  used Laravel backend for solve this issue. where i an using CURL for call zoom api. so after working fine.